# Rolling policy in logback.xml - roll file after x number of hours

Tags: spring-boot, logback

```xml
<rollingPolicy 
 class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
<!-- rollover hourly -->
<fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/server.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log
</fileNamePattern>
</rollingPolicy>
```

I m using this method now for hourly rollover but need to change this at 8hr rollover {i.e., we have 24 hr then 3 files will be created of 8hr log value each}.

Is there any solution to it?

Answer (score 1):

By default, logback does not provide a rolling policy implementation for such functionality. You can create your own rolling policy trigger for this by extending DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy and overriding the computeNextCheck method to perform the next roll after a specified multiple of the rolling time period it inferred from the file name pattern.

Custom Rolling Trigger Policy Class:

```java
import ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.NoAutoStart;
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy;

@NoAutoStart // @NoAutoStart prevents null pointer exception by stopping Joran from launching the start method before initialization
public class ArbitraryTimeRollingTriggerPolicy<E> extends DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy<E> {
    // Setters and getters are required to set times inside logback configuration xml file
    private int times;
    
    public int getTimes() {
        return times;
    }

    public void setTimes(int times) {
        this.times = times;
    }

    @Override
    protected void computeNextCheck() {
        nextCheck = rc.getEndOfNextNthPeriod(dateInCurrentPeriod, times).getTime();
    }
}
```

The rolling policy to use inside your appender in logback config:

```xml
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/server.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log</fileNamePattern>
    <!-- Custom Rolling Trigger Policy -->
    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="<YOUR-PACKAGE>.ArbitraryTimeRollingTriggerPolicy">
        <!-- Number of hours, after which you want to rotate the file -->
        <times>8</times>
    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
</rollingPolicy>
```